# The area of a right spherical triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Is there a compact formula for the area (excess angle – assuming a unit sphere)  of a right spherical triangle given its side lengths $a$ and $b$?

[image]

As explained in an answer to [an earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9819) about the area of a generic spherical triangle, the excess angle $E$ is given by
$$\tan\frac E4=\sqrt{\tan\frac{a+b+c}4\tan\frac{-a+b+c}4\tan\frac{a-b+c}4\tan\frac{a+b-c}4}$$
However, I do not have $c$. Of course, I can use [Napier's rules for right spherical triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Napier.27s_rules_for_right_spherical_triangles) to find $c$.

I thought about using integration in spherical coordinates (assuming B is the north pole and equating $a$ and $c$ with polar and azimuthal angles respectively). That approach, however, requires knowing the exact representation of the great circle that connects $A$ to $B$ in the coordinate chart.

Comment: Probably just simplify the formula?

Comment: Note that there is also the equivalent of the Pythagorean Theorem ([Theorem 4.3](http://math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/spheretrig.pdf)) to get $c$: $$\cos(c)=\cos(a)\cos(b)$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Theorem 9.2 of [this document](http://math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/spheretrig.pdf), it is shown that the area of a spherical right triangle, $E$, is given by
$$
\tan\left(\frac E2\right)=\tan\left(\frac a2\right)\tan\left(\frac b2\right)
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the two legs of the right spherical triangle.

Comment: Wow. I didn’t know that. Much swifter than my primitive method.

Answer (score 7):

Napier’s Rules do it easily. The Rule that helps you is $\sin b=\tan a\cot A$, in other words,
\begin{align}
\tan A&=\frac{\tan a}{\sin b}&A&=\arctan\left(\frac{\tan a}{\sin b}\right)\,,\\
\tan B&=\frac{\tan b}{\sin a}&B&=\arctan\left(\frac{\tan b}{\sin a}\right)\,,\\
\text{area}&=A+B-\frac\pi2\,.
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) I think this can be worked into the formula in my answer.

Comment: Very likely, @robjohn. I was just too lazy to try.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Todhunter's *Spherical Trigonometry*](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19770) (section VIII example 4):
$$\sin\frac E2=\sin\frac a2\sin\frac b2\sec\frac c2$$
$$\cos\frac E2=\cos\frac a2\cos\frac b2\sec\frac c2$$
Then
$$\tan\frac E2=\tan\frac a2\tan\frac b2$$
According to item 99 of the same source, $E=A+B+C-\pi$ for any triangle on the unit sphere. When $C=\frac\pi2$:
$$E=A+B-\frac\pi2$$

Comment: (+1) If you look at example 4. in section VIII (p.78) and divide the formula for $\sin\left(\frac12E\right)$ by the formula for $\cos\left(\frac12E\right)$, you get the formula in my answer.

Comment: @robjohn Worked in.