# Proving a formula for spherical triangles

Tags: spherical-geometry

I'm trying to prove the following formula.

> Given a spherical triangle with side lengths  $a,b,c$ and interior angles $ \alpha,\beta,\gamma $ prove the following formula 
>   $$2\sin \frac{A}{2} =\frac{\sqrt{\sin(s) \sin(s-a) \sin(s-b) \sin(s-c)}}{\cos \frac{a}{2}\cos\frac{b}{2}\cos\frac{c}{2}}$$ 
>   where $A= \alpha+\beta+\gamma -\pi$ and $s=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)$.

I wanted to show that 
$$2 \sin \frac{A}{2}\cos \frac{a}{2}\cos\frac{b}{2}\cos\frac{c}{2} = \sqrt {\sin(s) \sin(s-a)\sin(s-b)\sin(s-c)} .$$

So far I was able to prove that

$$\sqrt {\sin(s) \sin(s-a)\sin(s-b)\sin(s-c)} = \sin(a)\sin(b)\sin(\gamma)$$

$$\sin(a)=2\sin\frac{a}{2} \cos\frac{a}{2}$$

$$\sin(b)=2\sin\frac{b}{2} \cos\frac{b}{2}$$

so I get

$$\sqrt {\sin(s) \sin(s-a)\sin(s-b)\sin(s-c)} = 2\sin\frac{a}{2} \cos\frac{a}{2} \cdot 2\sin\frac{b}{2} \cos\frac{b}{2} \cdot 
\sin(\gamma)$$
$$ = 4\sin\frac{a}{2}\sin\frac{b}{2}\sin(\gamma)\cos\frac{a}{2}\cos\frac{b}{2}.$$

Now I only have to show that $2\sin \frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{c}{2} =4\sin\frac{a}{2}\sin\frac{b}{2}\sin(\gamma)$, 
or equivalently $\sin \frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{c}{2} =2\sin\frac{a}{2}\sin\frac{b}{2}\sin(\gamma)$.

Since I know that $A-(\alpha+\beta)+\pi= \gamma $,  it follows 
$$2\sin\frac{a}{2}\sin\frac{b}{2}\sin(\gamma)=2\sin\frac{a}{2}\sin\frac{b}{2}\sin(A-(\alpha+\beta)+\pi).$$
But I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: That looks like a spherical version of Heron's formula. FWIW, the usual version, aka L'Huilier's formula uses tangents, as shown in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66731/207316

Comment: Your $A$ is usually denoted by $E$ for spherical excess.