# Probability a random spherical triangle has area $> \pi$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

From Michigan State University's [Herzog contest](https://math.msu.edu/herzog/):

> <sub>[Problem 6, 1981](https://math.msu.edu/herzog/Exams/Herzog%20Exam%2019810001.pdf)</sub>
>
> Three points are taken at random on a unit sphere. What is the probability that the area of the spherical triangle exceeds the area of a great circle?

I assume we always take the unique proper spherical triangle, with sides and angles not greater than $\pi$. I assume "the area of a great circle" is the plane area $\pi$, since a proper spherical triangle never has area larger than the spherical area $2 \pi$ on each side of a great circle. I assume the random distribution is uniform, such that the probability each point is within a given measurable subset of the sphere is proportional to the spherical area of that subset.

First, given triangle vertices $A,B,C$ on the unit sphere, we can rotate and/or mirror the coordinate system so that $C = (0,0,1)$, $A$ is on the $x \geq 0, y=0$ half-plane, and $B$ is on the $y \geq 0$ hemisphere. Label the side lengths opposite $A$, $B$, and $C$ as $a$, $b$, and $c$ respectively. Label the (dihedral) angles at $A$, $B$, and $C$ as $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ respectively. Ignore a degenerate triangle case with any of these variables exactly equal to $0$ or $\pi$; this happens with probability zero. Then all six variables are in the interval $\{a,b,c,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\} \subset (0,\pi)$. We can parameterize the probability distribution as:

$$ \begin{align*}
 P(a < a_0) &= \frac{1-\cos a_0}{2} \\
 P(b < b_0) &= \frac{1-\cos b_0}{2} \\
 P(\gamma < \gamma_0) &= \frac{\gamma_0}{\pi}
\end{align*}$$

Variables $a$, $b$, and $\gamma$ are independent, so the overall probability density function is

$$ dP = \frac{1}{4\pi} \sin a \sin b\, da\, db\, d\gamma $$

The spherical area $\sigma$ of the triangle is

$$ \sigma = \alpha + \beta + \gamma - \pi $$

The outcome $\sigma > \pi$ is only possible if $\gamma > \frac{\pi}{2}$, since the spherical triangle covers a subset of the region between the planes containing $\{O,A,C\}$ and $\{O,A,B\}$ with area, $2 \gamma$. Similarly $\sigma > \pi$ implies $\alpha > \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\beta > \frac{\pi}{2}$.

We also have [Napier's analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Napier%27s_analogies)

$$ \tan \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} = \frac{\cos \frac{a-b}{2}}{\cos \frac{a+b}{2}} \cot \frac{\gamma}{2} $$

Since $\{a,b\} \subset (0, \pi)$, $|a-b|<\pi$ and $\cos \frac{a-b}{2} > 0$. If $\sigma > \pi$ then $\{\alpha, \beta, \gamma\} \subset (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)$ which implies $\tan \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} < 0$ and $\cot \frac{\gamma}{2} > 0$. Therefore $\cos \frac{a+b}{2} < 0$, and $\frac{a+b}{2} > \frac{\pi}{2}$.

So given $\{\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \frac{a+b}{2}\} \subset (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)$, all these inequalities are equivalent:

$$ \begin{align*}
\sigma &> \pi \\
 \alpha + \beta + \gamma &> 2\pi \\
 \pi - \frac{\gamma}{2} &< \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \\
 \tan \left(\pi - \frac{\gamma}{2}\right) &< \tan \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \\
 -\tan \frac{\gamma}{2} &< \frac{\cos \frac{a-b}{2}}{\cos \frac{a+b}{2}} \cot \frac{\gamma}{2} \\
\tan^2 \frac{\gamma}{2} &> - \cos \frac{a-b}{2}\, \sec \frac{a+b}{2} \\
\gamma &> 2\tan^{-1} \sqrt{- \cos \frac{a-b}{2}\, \sec \frac{a+b}{2}} = \gamma_L(a,b)
\end{align*}$$

where the function $\gamma_L(a,b)$ is defined where $0 \leq a \leq \pi$, $0 \leq b \leq \pi$, and $a+b>\pi$.
The probability in question is

\begin{align}P(\sigma > \pi) &= \int_0^\pi \int_{\pi-a}^\pi \int_{\gamma_L(a,b)}^\pi \frac{1}{4\pi} \sin a \sin b\, d\gamma\, db\, da\\&= \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_{\pi-a}^\pi [\pi - \gamma_L(a,b)] \sin a \sin b\, db\, da\end{align}

I've found we can also write

$$ \gamma_L(a,b) = \pi - \cos^{-1}\left(\cot \frac{a}{2} \cot \frac{b}{2}\right) $$

Either way, integration by parts can get rid of the inverse trig function in the integrand, leaving a square root, but I haven't been able to make much progress beyond that in solving the definite integral.

Wolfram Alpha gives the numeric answer as apparently $\frac{1}{6}$ [(1)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double%20integral%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangeend2%22%7D%20-%3E%22pi%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangeend1%22%7D%20-%3E%22pi%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%221%2F%284%20pi%29%20*%20%28pi%20-%202*arctan%28sqrt%28-cos%28%28a-b%29%2F2%29%2Fcos%28%28a%2Bb%29%2F2%29%29%29%29%20sin%28a%29%20sin%28b%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22intvariable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22a%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangestart1%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22intvariable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22b%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangestart2%22%7D%20-%3E%22pi-a%22) [(2)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double%20integral%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangeend2%22%7D%20-%3E%22pi%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangeend1%22%7D%20-%3E%22pi%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%221%2F%284%20pi%29%20*%20%28arccos%28cot%28a%2F2%29*cot%28b%2F2%29%29%29%20sin%28a%29%20sin%28b%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22intvariable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22a%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangestart1%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22intvariable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22b%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangestart2%22%7D%20-%3E%22pi-a%22). But it seems it can't solve it symbolically either.

Given this was in a limited-time competition, maybe there's some other simpler way to go about this. Some sort of symmetry grouping related points or triangles? How can we prove the exact probability?

Comment: isn't it kind of begging for the half-tangent substitution? Otherwise, I would express things like $\arccos, \arctan $ etc with its complex representation and attempt a contour integral.

Comment: I think the area of a great circle is the $2\pi$ solid angle represented by either side.

Comment: for what it's worth, after half-tangent substitutions, then integral is:
$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^{1/x}\dfrac{4\arccos(xy)xy}{\pi(1+x^2)^2(1+y^2)^2}dxdy = \dfrac{1}{6}$$
also confirmed by calculator.

Comment: @RossMillikan That would mean the probability is zero; not an extremely interesting question.

Comment: @ascheplerOK I see that.

Comment: Writing $a$, $b$, $c$ for the side lengths of the triangle, the area is $>\pi$ if and only if $\cos a + \cos b + \cos c < -1$. I found this by taking L'Huilier's Formula https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66731/448 and having Mathematica expand the tangents into $e^{ia}$, $e^{ib}$ and $e^{ic}$. Maybe this helps?

Comment: It would be an interesting (and quite a non-trivial) exercise to generalise this to $n$ points on an $n$-sphere and comparing their enclosed area with that of an $(n-1)$-sphere.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Certainly seems like there's potential. But while any two of $a,b,c$ are independent, the set of all three is dependent with no obvious simple way to parameterize the probability.

Comment: I have one more comment, but no solution to the original question. Let $u$, $v$, $w$ be the vertices of the triangle. Then $\text{Area}(uvw) > \pi$ if and only if the vector $u+v+w$ is inside the sphere. Proof: $(u+v+w)^2 = 3 + 2 (u\cdot v + u \cdot w + v \cdot w) = 3+2(\cos a+\cos b+\cos c)$ in the notation of my previous comment. But I don't see an easy way to get this probability, either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The substitution $u=\cot(a/2)\cot(b/2)$ yields $$I(a)=\int_{\pi-a}^\pi\arccos\left(\cot\frac a2\cot\frac b2\right)\sin b\,db=\int_0^1\frac{4u\tan^2(a/2)\arccos u}{(1+u^2\tan^2(a/2))^2}\,du$$ so that $$P(\sigma>\pi)=\frac1{4\pi}\int_0^\pi I(a)\sin a\,da=\frac4\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}J(a)\sin^2a\tan a\,da$$ where $\displaystyle J(a)=\int_0^1\frac{u\arccos u}{(1+u^2\tan^2a)^2}\,du$. Integration by parts yields \begin{align}J(a)&=-\frac{\arccos u}{2(1+u^2\tan^2a)\tan^2a}\bigg\vert_0^1-\frac1{2\tan^2a}\int_0^1\frac{du}{(1+u^2\tan^2a)\sqrt{1-u^2}}\\&=\frac\pi{4\tan^2a}-\frac1{2\tan^2a}\cdot\frac\pi{2\sqrt{\tan^2a+1}}\\&=\frac{\pi(1-\cos a)}{4\tan^2a}\end{align} where the last integral is evaluated by taking $t=u/\sqrt{1-u^2}$. Therefore, \begin{align}P(\sigma>\pi)=\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\cos a)\sin a\cos a\,da=\frac16.\end{align} Not sure if there is a quicker geometrical answer.